# Comparison of API results and database results in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am working on mapping database results with the results from the API which is coming in order to show the room with minimum rates and other unique rooms which are present in the array.
           I have created two multidimensional arrays one for my database results and other one for the API based results. So that i can compare values and show the least price for the room which is present in both API results and database results  and other remaining values which are unique in both the ways
           Following are the two arrays that i created

```
 $arr1  =  [0] => Array
                (
                    [roomName] => Standard
                    [ratePlan] => CPAI
                    [roomRate] => 10000
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [roomName] => Standard
                    [ratePlan] => MAP
                    [roomRate] => 11000
                )

        $arr2 = [0] => Array
                (
                    [roomName] => Standard
                    [ratePlan] => CP
                    [roomRate] => 9000
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [roomName] => Standard
                    [ratePlan] => MAP
                    [roomRate] => 10800
                )
```

I need to show the results based on the room name its rate plan and its minimum rate.For that i need to compare above two arrays on room name , room plan and room rate.
                   For e.g. In first array there standard room with MAP plan having rate 11000 and second array same room with same plan having rate 10800.So i need to show 10800 room and other remaining rooms.
                   One things i have to show other remaining results too.
                   How can i solve this problem.

Comment: I tried using for each for iterating two arrays but is is giving me single value multiple times

Answer (score 2):

Check below code.

```
<?php

$arr1  =   array(
    array (
                'roomName' => 'Standard',
                'ratePlan' => 'CPAI',
                'roomRate' => 10000
            ),
      array
            (
                'roomName' => 'Standard',
                'ratePlan' => 'MAP',
                'roomRate' => 11000
            ));

$arr2  =   array(
    array (
                'roomName' => 'Standard',
                'ratePlan' => 'CPAI',
                'roomRate' => 10000
            ),
      array
            (
                'roomName' => 'New',
                'ratePlan' => 'MAP',
                'roomRate' => 10800
            ));

$data = array_merge($arr1,$arr2);



// Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    $roomRate[$key]  = $row['roomRate'];
}

// Sort the data with roomRate Ascending
// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($roomRate, SORT_ASC,  $data);
```

Update code for all,

```
 // Obtain a list of columns
foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
$roomName[$key]  = $row['roomName'];
$ratePlan[$key]  = $row['ratePlan'];
$roomRate[$key]  = $row['roomRate'];
}


// Add $data as the last parameter, to sort by the common key
array_multisort($roomName,SORT_ASC, $ratePlan, SORT_ASC, $roomRate, SORT_ASC,  $data);
```

Comment: I have to compare the first room name if it is same then its plan and then rate.If minimum i have to show

Comment: it is not giving any results

Comment: I want results like this [0] => Array (   [hotelId] => 51991,  [roomId] => 6613, [roomName] => Standard, [ratePlan] => EP,[roomRate] => 9000)
[1] => Array([hotelId] => 51991,  [roomId] => 6614, [roomName] => Standard,[ratePlan] => CPAI,[roomRate] => 10000 [2] => Array(  [hotelId] => 51991,[roomId] => 10176, [roomName] => Standard,[ratePlan] => MAP,  [roomRate] => 10800  )

Comment: @varadmayee what is the input ?

Comment: means i am not understanding and did you understand my question

Comment: @varadmayee, I understood, so i wrote the code, but you have not mentioned the order of rate plan, means , how they will be sort ?

Comment: No not like that dude you have to first check in two arrays room names are matching or not if room name matched check there respective plan if plan also match then check its rate and show rate which is minimum.           e.g if i have 2 standard rooms with MAP plan with rate 10800 and 11000 so i will show standard room MAP plan and 10800 price other one will be bared.

Comment: @varadmayee , did u run the code?you need to update your question, with possible input and expected outputs, as it is confusing,MyCode is working in this way,  First all room, then room sort in plans then plans sort in rate. as you said you need all result.

Comment: I run your code but i need the output like if two room names are equal then check its plan if two plans are equal then check rate the room with minimum rate i have to show and other remaining rooms.Now is it clear to you :)

Comment: please check link http://codepad.org/NtAppj6n and output, i hope that will fulfill your need, change your input and test that code, in any case, let me know

Comment: I want to add three fields in $arr1,$arr2 these fields are hotelId,roomid and one other parameter how to add that

Comment: Excuse me @varadmayee,  We are here to help and to share the knowledge, not for the coding, if you need me to write your code then you can contact me. Thanks